# How to group array of objects with same key value pair

Tags: ios, swift4

I have an array of dictionaries with same key value pairs.

```
[
  { "amount": "10" }, 
  { "amount": "20" },
  { "amount": "30" },
  { "amount": "20" },
  { "amount": "10" },
  { "amount": "10" }
]
```

I need to group this based on same key values.

Expected sample result:

There are 3x 10's, 2x 20's and 1x 30's

How do I achieve this?

Comment: You could use an `NSCountedSet`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let array = [ ["amount": "10"], ["amount": "20"], ["amount": "30"], ["amount": "20"], ["amount": "10"], ["amount": "10"] ]
var result: [String: Int] = [:]
let key = "amount"
array.forEach {
    guard let value = $0[key] else { return }
    result[value, default: 0] += 1
}

print("\(result["10"])") // 3
```